# Is there a faster way through list comprehension to iterate through two dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have two dataframes, one contains screen names/display names and another contains individuals, and I am trying to create a third dataframe that contains all the data from each dataframe in a new row for each time a last name appears in the screen name/display name. Functionally this will create a list of possible matching names.  My current code, which works perfectly but very slowly, looks like this:

```
# Original Social Media Screen Names
# cols = 'userid','screen_name','real_name'
usernames = pd.read_csv('social_media_accounts.csv')

# List Of Individuals To Match To Accounts
# cols = 'first_name','last_name'
individuals = pd.read_csv('individuals_list.csv')

userid, screen_name, real_name, last_name, first_name = [],[],[],[],[]
for index1, row1 in individuals.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in usernames.iterrows():
        if (row2['Screen_Name'].lower().find(row1['Last_Name'].lower()) != -1) | (row2['Real_Name'].lower().find(row1['Last_Name'].lower()) != -1):
            userid.append(row2['UserID'])
            screen_name.append(row2['Screen_Name'])
            real_name.append(row2['Real_Name'])
            last_name.append(row1['Last_Name'])
            first_name.append(row1['First_Name'])

cols = ['UserID', 'Screen_Name', 'Real_Name', 'Last_Name', 'First_Name']
index = range(0, len(userid))
match_list = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=cols)
match_list = match_list.fillna('')
match_list['UserID'] = userid
match_list['Screen_Name'] = screen_name
match_list['Real_Name'] = real_name
match_list['Last_Name'] = last_name
match_list['First_Name'] = first_name
```

Because I need the whole row from each column, the list comprehension methods I have tried do not seem to work.

Comment: Can you show the sample of two data sets and the output you are looking for?

Comment: The data sets are straight forward: usernames has 3 cols: userid (int), screen_name (str lower case no spaces or special characters), real_name (str). individuals has 2 cols: Last_Name (str), and First_Name (str). The goal is to have a dataframe for all instances where a screen_name or real_name has the same string sequence as an instance of Last_Name, and store the userid, screen_name, real_name, last_name, and first_name for each one of those occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is to iterate through a dataframe faster.  Doing that with a list comprehension is, taking data out of a pandas dataframe, handling it using operations in python, then putting it back in a pandas dataframe.  The fastest way (currently, with small data) would be to handle it using pandas iteration methods.
The next thing you want to do is work with 2 dataframes.  There is a tool in pandas called `join`.

```
result = pd.merge(usernames, individuals, on=['Screen_Name', 'Last_Name'])
```

After the merge you can do your filtering.

Here is the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html